# How to get VMware guest MAC address from the console?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I am trying to get the MAC address of a VMware guest from the command line in ESXi 6.

The vSphere client shows the MAC address of the network adapters, which are configured as "automatic".

The command

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/get.config <id>
```

shows me many of the details of that particular guest, but not the MAC addresses of the network cards.

Is there a command that I can run from the VMware shell that displays the MAC address of a VMWare guest?

Comment: This command `vim-cmd vmsvc/get.config <id>` gives back "False MAC addresses"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vim-cmd vmsvc/device.getdevices <id>` will show you details about the virtual devices of the VM, including the MAC adresses.

Comment: This may gives the mac at the moment of the VM creation but not the current mac address.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I just checked with a VM where I changed the MAC address a couple of weeks ago. The command shows it's current MAC address.

Comment: Maybe it needs something to be installed in the VM?

Answer (score 2):

vim-cmd hostsvc/net/info | grep "mac ="

Comment: This shows the mac addresses of the host, not of the guests.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but thought I'd share a one-liner to get all of them (I was trying to locate an unknown VM)...

```
for VID in `vim-cmd vmsvc/getallvms | awk '{print $1}'`; do echo ${VID} `vim-cmd vmsvc/device.getdevices ${VID} | grep macAddress` ; done
```

From there, you can use the VID with the macAddress you're looking for to run this to identify the actual VM:

```
vim-cmd vmsvc/get.config 2 | grep "name"
```